# Access to restricted URI denied when linking to LESS css

Tags: css, less, css-frameworks

I just downloaded the [semantic CSS](http://semantic.gs/) and was running the examples but saw the following error on Firefox

```
Access to restricted URI denied

file:///C:/semanticcss/examples/fixed/fixed.less
```

Below is the code in the example page

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fixed.less" type="text/less" media="screen" />

<!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="../../js/less-1.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Are you running the site on your local machine? if so, do you have some sort of server environment running (ex: apache)?

Comment: yeah, I have apache running, however, this is just a simple html page and does not access the same port as apache (8080)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on purpose. Local files may only read other local files in the same directory or sub-directories.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[sudo] npm install less -g
```

Then it shouldn't have any problems with the directories. My system (MBP) did the same thing until I did this. The main problem was that it doesn't know where the LESS compiler is located. You will more than likely need root privileges to run the command, hence [sudo] is system dependent.

Hope this helps.